# If $\lim_{\{f(x),g(x)\}\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, then $\lim_{\{f(x),g(x)\}\to\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0$. Is that true?

Tags: limits

I think that the following statement is true;

If $\lim_{\{f(x),g(x)\}\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, then $\lim_{\{f(x),g(x)\}\to\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0$.

But I haven't learned the rools of limits yet, so I don't know if it is.

Can anyone make me sure that it is true, or tell me that it's not...?

Comment: What does the limit as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ go to infinity mean? What if they go to infinity at multiple points? Do you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{}{}\right)$?

Comment: look at $f(x) =x, g(x)= x+1$

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, I didn't think of that... It's simple.

Comment: It's worth noting the converse isn't true either. For example, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2x}$, $g(x) = \frac 1x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x)=x+2$. Or perhaps even better is $f(x) = g(x)+1$

What is your limit for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

What is your limit for $f(x)-g(x)$?

Edit:
In fact the limit can be $\infty$ if one sets say $f(x)  = g(x)+\ln(g(x))$.

Comment: Thank you, it's simple. Maybe can I ask this, will the limit $\lim f(x)-g(x)$ exist? or it can be infinity?

Comment: I know for certain you can make the limit be impossible to resolve by making the difference say $\cos(x)$.

 You could make the limit infinite by adding in say $\ln(x)$ or $\ln(g(x))$ where the limit will be zero for the proportion, but infinite on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, where $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}h(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark